# Unable to get key events for touchscreen keyboard from /dev/input/event1

Tags: android, linux-kernel, low-level-io

I am unable to get key events from /dev/input/event1. What i'm able to filter out from its output is absolute X and Y touch coordinates from event code 53 and 54. I'm confused why there's no output with event code 1 when i type on my soft keyboard. I want to know which key user presses and with how much pressure. Hope you understand my problem.

I'm on rooted Samsung Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 0):

Because the soft keyboard doesn't work like that.  It isn't a part of the OS, its an application.  So the keyboard app will be given touch events, and it will call java functions to tell the main app what was pressed.  It doesn't go through hardware input channels at all after the press.  The OS doesn't know what keys are where, ever.

Most keyboards don't even generate key events-  they generate word at a time output via commitText.

Basically, you can't do what you want in the way you want.  The only way to know what keys were pressed, without altering the OS, is to be on the other side of the InputConnection processing commands from the InputMethodService (keyboard).

Comment: Thanks @Gabe for guiding. Would you please elaborate how to on the other of the InputConnection. I didn't get you. Actually what i want to do is hookup with existing keyboard somehow to get key events. Is this possible somehow? Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Most keyboards don't do key events at all, or only do so under worst case conditions.  The API used to communicate between a view and the soft keyboard is called InputConnection.  A view that accepts keyboard input will create an InputConnection and return it to the framework upon request by the framework.  The two applications then directly communicate via IPC over that object.  They do not go through a traditional linux keyboard events at all-  only physical keys do that.